# Keras Converting Functional Model to Model Subclass

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to use Keras **Model Subclassing** to rewrite a **Functional model**, but in the new model subclass, the summary generation does not work.

For reference, here is the **functional model** and its output.

```py
filters = 32

# placeholder for inputs
inputs = Input(shape=[16, 16, 16, 12])  

# L-hand side of UNet
conv1 = DoubleConv3D(filters*1)(inputs)
pool1 = MaxPooling3D()(conv1)
...

# middle bottleneck
conv5 = DoubleConv3D(filters*5)(pool4)

# R-hand side of UNet
rsdc6 = ConcatConv3D(filters*4)(conv5, conv4)
conv6 = DoubleConv3D(filters*4)(rsdc6)
...

# sigmoid activation
outputs = Conv3D(1, (1, 1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(conv9)

model = Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])
model.summary()
```

```py
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_29 (InputLayer)           (None, 16, 16, 16, 1 0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
conv3d_111 (Conv3D)             (None, 16, 16, 16, 3 10400       input_29[0][0]                   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
...
```

And the **Model Subclass** looks like:

```py
class UNet3D(Model):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(UNet3D, self).__init__(name="UNet3D", **kwargs)        
        self.filters = 32

    def __call__(self, inputs):

        # L-hand side of UNet
        conv1 = DoubleConv3D(self.filters*1)(inputs)
        pool1 = MaxPooling3D()(conv1)
        ...

        # middle bottleneck
        conv5 = DoubleConv3D(self.filters*5)(pool4)

        # R-hand side of UNet
        rsdc6 = ConcatConv3D(self.filters*4)(conv5, conv4)
        conv6 = DoubleConv3D(self.filters*4)(rsdc6)
        ...

        # sigmoid activation
        outputs = Conv3D(1, (1, 1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(conv9)
        return outputs

unet3d = UNet3D()
unet3d.build(Input(shape=[None, None, None, 1]))
unet3d.summary()
```

However, instead of outputting the layers and number of parameters, the summary gives

```py
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
Total params: 0
Trainable params: 0
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Initially, I believed this was an error with not calling `build` before calling summary, and tried to both explicitly call the function and adding an `InputLayer` before the first Convolution layer, as noted in this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55909624/4241779). However, neither solutions help in fixing the summary generation on the model subclass.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution to this Model subclassing problem by looking at the following [example](https://github.com/jayleverett/modular-unet/blob/master/unet.py). Credit should go to the author of that repo.

One way to create convert a Keras Functional into a Model subclass is to create and call a function which replicates the model initialization, e.g. `Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs])`. Here, we do that with the `_build` function.

```py
class UNet3D(Model):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):

        # Initialize model parameters.
        self.filters = 32
        ...

        # Initialize model.
        self._build(**kwargs)

    def __call__(self, inputs):

        # L-hand side of UNet
        conv1 = DoubleConv3D(self.filters*1)(inputs)
        pool1 = MaxPooling3D()(conv1)
        ...

        # middle bottleneck
        conv5 = DoubleConv3D(self.filters*5)(pool4)

        # R-hand side of UNet
        rsdc6 = ConcatConv3D(self.filters*4)(conv5, conv4)
        conv6 = DoubleConv3D(self.filters*4)(rsdc6)
        ...

        # sigmoid activation
        outputs = Conv3D(1, (1, 1, 1), activation='sigmoid')(conv9)
        return outputs

    def _build(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Replicates Model(inputs=[inputs], outputs=[outputs]) of functional model.
        """
        # Replace with shape=[None, None, None, 1] if input_shape is unknown.
        inputs  = Input(shape=[16, 16, 16, 12])
        outputs = self.__call__(inputs)
        super(UNet3D, self).__init__(name="UNet3D", inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs, **kwargs) 

unet3d = UNet3D()
unet3d.summary()
```