# Unable to get the summary while building custom model using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I have a very simple model as shown below:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Model(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, input_shape=None, name="cus_model", **kwargs):
        super(Model, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        
    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(input_shape=input_shape, units=32)
        
    def call(self, input_tensor):
        return self.dense1(input_tensor)

input_shape=(1,10)
model = Model()
model.build(input_shape=input_shape) # Note the .build call
model.summary()
```

I've added `model.build()` call as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55909624/2679778), but still I'm getting following error:

```
ValueError: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling `build()` or calling `fit()` with some data, or specify an `input_shape` argument in the first layer(s) for automatic build.
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to build the network by modifying the line

```
model.build(input_shape=input_shape) # Note the .build call
```

with

```
_ = model(tf.zeros([1,10]))
```

From [tensorflow documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/customization/custom_layers#implementing_custom_layers):

> Calling the layer `.builds` it.

Comment: Seems a nice trick. Instead of manually trying to call .build, let tf does that by calling the model.