# Model.fit() is returning "This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling `build()` or calling `fit()` with some data"

Tags: python, tensorflow, artificial-intelligence

When running a model.fit(train_ds, epochs=10, validation_data=val_ds), I'm receiving the error "ValueError: This model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling `build()` or calling `fit()` with some data, or specify an `input_shape` argument in the first layer(s) for automatic build."

I'm very confused, because i'm trying to run exactly what the error is suggesting that needs to happen. I've followed the [structured data tutorial to the T](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/feature_columns).

I've verified that the datasets I'm passing contain
[data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIOA2.png)

Any help would be greatly appreciated... I'm spinning my wheels. Tried both tf 2.3.* and 2.4.*

```html
customersDf = pd.DataFrame({"Name":['joe','frank','bob','eleanore'],'target':[1,1,2,2,]})
train, test = train_test_split(customersDf, test_size = 0.2)
train, val = train_test_split(train, test_size = 0.2)
print(len(train))
print(len(test))
print(len(val))

batch_size = 2048

train_ds = df_to_dataset(train, batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = df_to_dataset(val, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)

test_ds = df_to_dataset(test, shuffle=False, batch_size=batch_size)

feature_columns = []

name1 = feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list(
      'Name', customersDf.Name.unique())

name1_embedding = feature_column.embedding_column(name1, dimension=12)

feature_columns.append(name1_embedding)

feature_layer = tf.keras.layers.DenseFeatures(feature_columns)

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
  feature_layer,
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  layers.Dropout(.1),
  layers.Dense(1)
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
              
model.fit(train_ds, epochs=10, validation_data=val_ds)
```

Comment: You must show a [example]. Where is `train_ds` defined? (if it's too large or must be loaded from somewhere, make some dummy data so it's runnable/produce the mentioned runtime error)

Comment: did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55908188/this-model-has-not-yet-been-built-error-on-model-summary

Comment: @DataMangler. According to tutorial, features_columns shouldn't be empty.  You must create other variables for reproducible example.

Comment: @JuanCamiloRiveraPalacio feature columns are appended here feature_columns.append(name1_embedding)

Comment: @user202729 sorry, added more code, should be easier to reproduce now

Comment: The error is saying build the model first, Add this code snippet `model.build(input_shape)` before calling `model.fit() function`. Thanks!