# This model has not yet been built. Why?

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, resnet, image-classification

I have created this base model, and it works correctly:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.applications import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Flatten, Dense, Dropout

base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False, 
                      weights='imagenet', 
                      input_shape=(150, 150, 3))
base_model.trainable = True
```

But when I try to extend the original model (or even when I copy the whole code into the model) I get an error:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(ResNet50(include_top=False, 
                      weights='imagenet', 
                      input_shape=(150, 150, 3)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(512, activation="sigmoid"))
model.summary()
```

The error says

```
The model has not yet been built. Build the model first by calling 
'build()' or calling 'fit()' with some data, or specify an 'input_shape'
argument in the first layer(s) for automatic build.
```

Comment: I can answer your question, but in order for it to be useful for other people in SackOverflow, you need to write a proper question. This means you have to write (in formatted block of text) the code and the errors, and avoid adding links to images with code that cannot be searched over or referenced later. Keep in mind that StackOverflow is not here only to answer your question, but to build collective knowledge. PS: If you do it properly, I guarantee an answer.

Comment: Thank you for inform me about it. I have problem about create the code in the question (or show the picture without link) and usually the other help me edit it. But I've tried to edit it properly. May you help me to answer it? @ibarrond

Comment: Answered! I see your english is not perfect, and it is ok to rely on other people to correct some grammar/typo mistakes. However, you should always ask questions providing pieces of code for other programmers to try it out and arrive to your same error. Your edit was nice! well done.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This model has not yet been built error on model.summary()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55908188/this-model-has-not-yet-been-built-error-on-model-summary)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should google the error (just google "The model has not yet been built"), as it is a common error and already in the first hit I found an answer in StackOverflow ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55908188/this-model-has-not-yet-been-built-error-on-model-summary)). The first answer to this question ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55909624/9670056)) solves your issue directly.

Now, to answer your question anyway, you change the architecture of the model when you add layers, thus you need to build it again. To build it again, you should follow what the error message tells you, and call the `build()` function with your `input_shape`:

```py
#... your code
model.add(Dense(512, activation="sigmoid"))
model.build(input_shape=(150, 150, 3))
```